# A knotty problem in trigonometric equations

Tags: trigonometry

Solve the equation $$\tan^4 x + \tan^4 y  + 2\cot^2x \cot^2 y = 3 + \sin^2 (x+y) $$ for the values of *x* and *y*.

**Partial Solution**:
One can easily guess that $ x = \pi/4 $  and $y =  \pi/4$ satisfy the given equation. So one solution is $x = n \pi \pm \pi/4 , n \in \mathbb{z} $ and $ y = n \pi \pm \pi/4 , n \in \mathbb{z} $. But how do we prove that this is the only solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:AM-GM inequality says

$$\dfrac{\tan^4x+\tan^4y+\cot^2x\cot^2y+\cot^2x\cot^2y}4\ge1$$